# Is there any special reason that numpy.rint supports complex numbers and numpy.floor does not?

Tags: numpy, rounding, complex-numbers

I am just curious, is there any specific reason that numpy.rint does seem to support complex numbers e.g.

> np.rint(3.1+2.3j)

> (3+2j)

while numpy.floor numpy.ceil do not e.g.

> np.floor(3.1+2.3j)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> TypeError: ufunc 'floor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced >to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''*

I use them in fixed point hardware simulation and it's a bit annoying to have separate real and image parts handled for np.floor while np.rint handles complex numbers just fine...

Comment: Can you point to a source (wiki or other) that defines `floor` for complex values?  What does `math.floor` do?

Comment: `why` answers usually depend on knowledge of the development history; otherwise they are opinions or informed guesses.

Comment: floor() basically round toward minus infinity, should be same for real or complex numbers. just like np.rint() that rounds toward closest integer real or complex. numpy documents neither for floor() nor for rint() mention complexity.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The floor of the scalar x is the largest integer i, such that i <= x. It is often denoted as \lfloor x \rfloor.

By your reasoning `floor(1+2.3j)` should be `1+2j`, right?  Let's test it:

It is true by numpy's comparison rules:

```
In [259]: np.array([1+2j])<=np.array([1+2.3j])
Out[259]: array([ True])
```

but not Python `complex`:

```
In [254]: 1+2j<=1+2.3j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-254-982f3ee0b6f8>", line 1, in <module>
    1+2j<=1+2.3j
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'complex'
```

Python's implementation:

```
In [255]: import math
In [256]: math.floor(1+2.3j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-256-be3a7370c225>", line 1, in <module>
    math.floor(1+2.3j)
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

`sympy` is more explicit about generalization to complex:

> Floor is a univariate function which returns the largest integer
> value not greater than its argument. This implementation
> generalizes floor to complex numbers by taking the floor of the
> real and imaginary parts separately.

`Octave/MATLAB` is also explicit about its generalization.

I don't know if that generalization is mathematically robust or not.  The Wiki article only has one mention of the `complex`.  This `math` thread points out the ambiguity of this extension (due to the question of ordering of complex numbers).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095674/floor-function-in-complex-plane

Comment: True, but  the interesting thing is that numpy.rint which basically is just another type of rounding, does work with complex. It feels as if np.rint and np.floor where designed by people with completely different understanding of math.

Comment: What's the math about rounding of complex numbers?  I've seen discussions about `rounding up` or not for .5 values, but nothing about rounding complex.

Comment: Since complex number has real and imaginary component, both should be rounded, just like np.rint does. Maybe whoever designed np.rint was aware of exitance of complex numbers, while np.floor implementer was not.

Comment: You view floor as just a kind of rounding.  The python coders take the `i<=x` part the definition more seriously. It's not ignorance, but a choice not to generalize.  Mathematically the arguments can go either way.

Comment: Well, floor is literally "round to closes integer toward minus infinity" for every possible practical intent and purpose. And I would accept "chose not to generalize" if it would also apply to numpy.rint but it doesn't. IMO various choices to generalize or not depending on a specific function from the same family is awkward  to say the least, like many other things that have to do with complex number handling. But, eh, at least we get the tool for free.